# Hide anchor in URL when scrolling to anchorpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I've made a single page website (+ single posts) and a menu that scrolls to anchorpoints when clicking on them:

```
if ( window.location.hash ) scroll(0, 0);
        setTimeout( function() { scroll(0, 0); }, 1);

            $(function() {
                $('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1000, 'swing');
            });

            if(window.location.hash) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
                }, 1000, 'swing');
            }
        });

        var $root = $('html, body');
            $('a').on('click', function(event){

        var hash = this.hash;
        if (hash && this.href.slice(0, -hash.length-1) == location.href.slice(0, -location.hash.length-1)) {
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 'swing', function() {
                location.hash = hash;
            });
        return false;
            }
        });
```

But is it also possible to keep this function as it is, but hide the #anchor in the URL?

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the line that explicitly _sets_ the hash after the animation …?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can prevent the hashchange event:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```